# ¿Que se puede hacer cuando la persona que pregunta no marca una respuesta como aceptada, cuando el ya mencionó que le sirvió?

Tags: discusión

navegando por ahí, me encontré con [Esta pregunta.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/259527/c%C3%B3mo-puedo-modificar-el-atributo-selected-a-un-select-de-forma-din%C3%A1mica-con-php) En casos como ese, que el OP mencionó en un comentario que la respuesta es la que le sirvió, pero no se marca como respuesta... ¿se puede hacer algo? algún moderador puede marcar las respuestas como aceptadas en esos casos?